# from form asp button send param to method in controller

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I need to send true and false from button, to controller Quelist Action NeedHelpTrueOrFalse.

I can´t use Jquery with URL when this is in a ViewComponent

```
form asp-controller="QueList" asp-action="NeedHelpTrueOrFalse"


        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            if (item.IsUserItem)
            {                   
                <input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Problem Solved" class="btn btn-success" />
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                <input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Help" class="btn btn-success" />
            }
        }            
    </form>
```

in controller:

```
public IActionResult NeedHelpTrueOrFalse(bool trueOrFalse)
        {
            try
            {
                var dataManager = new DataManager(context);
                dataManager.HelpTrueOrFalse(User.Identity.Name, trueOrFalse);
                return ViewComponent("QueListViewComponent");
                            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, e.Message);
                return View();
            }

}
```

in datamanager:

```
  public void HelpTrueOrFalse (string UserName, bool trueOrFalse)

    {
        var user = context.Users
          .Where(o => o.UserName == UserName).SingleOrDefault();

        if(user != null)
        {
            user.NeedHelp = trueOrFalse;

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: share more details, like what is Action's Type (HttpGet or HttpPost), Parameters, etc. in Controller, and also what do you want  like on "Problem Solved" add true else false or what...

Comment: What do you mean by to sent true or false?

Comment: The button "problem solved", I want it to send false to action, so it can be set in DB. the other button should send true to the action

Answer (score 0):

If there is form submit then you can try like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.IsUserItem)
    {                   
        <input type="hidden" name="trueOrFalse" value="false" />
        <input type="submit" id="btnClick" value="Problem Solved" class="btn btn-success" />
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="trueOrFalse" value="true" />
        <input type="submit" id="btnClick" value="Help" class="btn btn-success" />
    }
}
```

Here it will submit `trueOrFalse` as parameter and you can set its value in hidden field whatever you want..

Comment: Can't get it to work, I'm new to this view Components (when wanting to display one model in layout and Another in index). Mabye it doesn't update properly, because nothing happens when pressing button